# Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src *"

Tags: fonts, content-security-policy

It's Showing error in Chrome Console.

> Refused to load the font 'data:font/woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAGVUABEAAAAAxuQAAQABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABHREVGAAABgAAAAC4AAAA0ArgC7UdQT1MAAAGwAAAQ6AAALgxKsqRTR1NVQgAAEpgAAAH3AAAELqI5y+RPUy8yAAAUkAAAAE8AAABgaGyBu2NtYXAAABTgAAABlAAAAkQkRATXY3Z0IAAAFnQAAABeAAAAugDsQf1mcGdtAAAW1AAABZcAAAvNb3/BHGdhc3AAABxsAAAACAAAAAgAAAAQZ2x5ZgAAHHQAAEApAAB3CtbiupxoZWFkAABcoAAAADYAAAA2BkubWWhoZWEAAFzYAAAAIAAAACQHFARfaG10eAAAXPgAAAI6AAAEEk4TN4Nsb2NhAABfNAAAAhIAAAISiLhpam1heHAAAGFIAAAAIAAAACACigzgbmFtZQAAYWgAAACUAAABHhQGLdJwb3N0AABh/AAAAq4AAASRk5y6n3ByZ...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' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src *".

Please provide me any suggestion?

Check error screenshot below
https://ibb.co/daTcyT

Answer (score 1):

If I understand [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/font-src) correctly, `*` matches any *source*, but what you want is to allow *data* to be loaded/interpreted. Try to change your `Content-Security-Policy` to `data:` instead of `*`.

For example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; font-src data:" />
```

But beware:

> `data:`
>
> Allows data: URIs to be used as a content source. This is insecure; an attacker can also inject arbitrary data: URIs. Use this sparingly and definitely not for scripts.